# How To Add a Category in Default Category using Custom Module/

Tags: magento

I want to Add a new category within Default Category at the time of my custom Module installation.
Can Anyone Help me to Do so

This my mysql setup script..

```
$this->startSetup();


$parentId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
// Force the store to be admin
Mage::app()->setUpdateMode(false);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath()) // set parent to be root category
    ->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
    ->setName('Subscription Plans')
    ->setUrlKey('subscription-plans')
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS')
    ->setIsAnchor(0)
    ->setIncludeInMenu(0)
    ->save();
$this->installEntities();

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: can you please post the setup install script of your custom module?

Comment: Please Check my setup install script

Comment: what is the name of the setup file?

Comment: setup is running i am creating some tables using that setup as well,but it doesn't create category

Comment: if you echo `$parentId;` or `Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID` does it show the values?

Comment: yes $parentId is printing 1/2 and Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID printing 0

Comment: if $parentId is printing 1/2, you need one value, i guess only 2. try using static 2 as $parentId = 2;

Comment: i found the solution when i am passing $parentid='1/2' it does works

Comment: ok, i posted an answer on ur previous same question, if that help you , please vote thanks,